# Fullcalendar SQL to get events that start before the view starts and end after the view ends

Tags: sql, fullcalendar

I'm having an issue with my SQL query that is being used to fetch events for fullcalendar, everything works fine unless an event starts before the current view starts, and ends after the current view ends, for example if I have an event that starts on a Monday and goes until Wednesday, in the day view for Tuesday it does not show up. This is because I'm not sure how to make an SQL query to get events that fit this criteria. My Current query is below:

```
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE start BETWEEN :start1 AND :end1 OR end BETWEEN :start AND :end ORDER BY start ASC');
$query->bindValue(':start1', $_POST['start']);
$query->bindValue(':end1', $_POST['end']);
$query->bindValue(':start', $_POST['start']);
$query->bindValue(':end', $_POST['end']);
$query->execute();
```

Is it possible to form an SQL query to get all events where the event's duration makes it be occurring during the view, but not starting or ending during the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People often overcomplicate "find out if two intervals overlap" - and I think that's what you're doing here. They try to enumerate all of the ways that the overlaps may occur. When, in fact, a very simple definition covers all of them:

Two intervals overlap if:

- the first starts before the second ends, *and*,
- the second starts before the first ends.

```
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE start < :end AND :start < end ORDER BY start ASC');
$query->bindValue(':start', $_POST['start']);
$query->bindValue(':end', $_POST['end']);
$query->execute();
```

The only variation you typically need to spend a few minutes considering are the `<` signs, and whether you consider two intervals to overlap if one starts at the same instant that the other one ends (if you want such intervals to be overlaps, you use `<=` instead)